# Cloud Functions for Firebase onLinkAccount event?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

My app uses anonymous accounts by default. When people link their gmail account, I want to trigger a Cloud Function that sends an email. There is an event when an account is created, but is there an event for when linking an account?

```
functions.auth.user().onCreate
```

Answer (score 2):

*firebaser here*

Such an event doesn't exist at the moment, but it sounds like a quite interesting idea. I'd recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).